# Setting up Paging with links in Angular template

Tags: angular, paging, routerlink

I have tried the below solution :

{{page}}

If I remove the {{page}} in the routerlink it works, otherwise it gives error.
But I need of course the page number inside the link so that I may direct to the proper page. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:) You can pass routerLink argument like array, where is second param can be variable.

```
<a style="display:inline-block" *ngFor="let page of pages" [routerLink]="['/searchflights',page]">
           {{page}}
</a>
```

Comment: This works, however I have a problem: When the url changes after I click the page link, the component does not get reloaded. I have my code in the component's constructor and that is not triggered, because the component is not reloaded. But If I manually type the link in the browser and press enter, the component is reloaded.

Comment: If you want to reload your component you should move it router outlet, and render it on router like that 'searchflights/:id':)

Answer (score 0):

Try making it like this, just by changing the comma positioning:

```
<a style="display:inline-block" *ngFor="let page of pages" [routerLink]="['/searchflights/'{{page}}]">
    {{page}}
</a>
```

Comment: @Prachi you have missed the `+` for concatnation `[routerLink]="['/searchflights/'+{{page}}]`